# Facebook does not allow post photo url, which refers to the Facebook's server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to use this picture url when I share post to the Facebook wall
https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/1509934_1399389213653861_1680466495_a.jpg.

But I get an error, which says: "An unknown error has occurred.". It's very strange, because when I try to use this picture url:
http://zastavki-oboi.ru/thumbs/oranjevyi_cvetochek-4636.jpg
I do not get any errors.

I really do not understand, why first one does not work, but second one works correctly!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to post to the `/feed` edge with an `object_attachment` specified.  The `object_attachment` being the Facebook object ID of the image you want to share.  The app user will also need to be the owner of that photo.

`object_attachment`

> Facebook ID for an existing picture in the person's photo albums to
>   use as the thumbnail image. They must be the owner of the photo, and
>   the photo cannot be part of a message attachment.

See under **Publishing**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#

And a note, if you only have the url of the image, the object ID should be the middle set of numbers in the filename.  1509934_**1399389213653861**_1680466495_a.jpg.

Comment: Ok, I understood. So, seem Facebook tracks photos, which refers on the irs server and does not allow post this pictures. Thank you